# Make Windows taskbar show/jump to windows on different desktops?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

The default behavior of the Windows 10 taskbar when multiple desktops are in use is to show only the programs open on the current desktop. Is there a way to show *all* programs on the taskbar, and to make it so clicking on a running program on another desktop switches desktops instead of opening a new Window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Windows setting that can be changed:

- Run *Settings*
- Open *System*
- Choose *Multitasking*
- Click the down-arrow under *On the taskbar, show windows that are open on*, and select *All desktops*.

[image]